# Run some codes when another form would closed

Tags: c#, winforms, formclosing

I have a winform with ID Form1, in this form I create new object of another form with ID Form2 and show it:

**codes in Form1:**

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.show();
```

I want run some codes in Form1 when user f2 would closed:

Please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    frm.FormClosed+= Form2Closed;
    frm.Show();

}

private void Form2Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //frm has been closed
}
```

Comment: frm has no attribute with name Closed

Comment: what do u mean by attribute ? `Closed` is a `event`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closed.aspx

Comment: it's Closed or FormClosed?

Comment: @Ehsan - please use the `FormClosed` event.

Comment: Yes, I used .NetframeWork 4 instead 4.5 thankyou